# IOException:Not connected Class: class net.rim.device.api.io.ConnectionClosedException in blackberry

Tags: exception, blackberry, connection

I'm getting the net.rim.device.api.io.ConnectionClosedException from my java code for Blackberry. Highlighted in below code is the line where Exception is raised.

```
hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);  

        hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + getBoundaryString());

        hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);           

        hc.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_ACCEPT_CHARSET,
                "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");

        hc.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH ,Integer.toString(fileBytes.length));

        OutputStream dout = hc.openOutputStream();

        dout.write(boundaryMessage.getBytes());
        dout.write(this.postBytes);
        dout.write(endBoundary.getBytes());             

        dout.close();

        int ch;     

        **is = hc.openInputStream();** //exception raised here

        if(hc.getResponseCode()== HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {                       
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1)
            {
                bos.write(ch);
            }
            res = bos.toByteArray();
            System.out.println("res loaded..");             
        }
        else {              
            System.out.println("Unexpected response code: " + hc.getResponseCode());            
            hc.close();
            return null;
        }             
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {           
        System.out.println("====IOException : "+e.getMessage()+" Class: "+e.getClass());                
    }
    catch(Exception e1)
        {
            //e1.printStackTrace();                 
            System.out.println("====Exception : "+e1.getMessage()+" Class: "+e1.getClass());    
        }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(bos != null)
                bos.close();

            if(is != null)
                is.close();

            if(hc != null)
                hc.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e2)
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();               
            System.out.println("====Exception : "+e2.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
```

What should I do to correct this? Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do not call `dout.close();` neither close any connections until you have done all things with this connection. If you want to flush your stream, invoke `dout.flush()`, but do not close it.

Comment: dout.close() does not close the connection, only the output stream. The flush() call could be useful. Another thing to try (I'm comparing it to my code) is getting the HTTP response code before opening the input stream. If it doesn't work, then it probably depends on something else. I see you are using a multipart request, are you sure the boundary strings are all Ok?

Comment: Thanks G B for you response. Yes,my boundary strings are OK.

Comment: Just to tell you,what I feel annoying about is that I have run this code several times when I had to upload other audio/text files. So this code should also work, but its not working here. The only thing I changed is
    dout.write(boundaryMessage.getBytes());
        dout.write(this.postBytes);
        dout.write(endBoundary.getBytes()); 
When I had only one dout.write(postbytes) previously, where <postbytes> was the whole chunk of bytes I had to write. Because of memory issues with ByteArrayOutputStream I had to edit my code. Can this be the problem..Writing 3 times on dout ?

Comment: I tried to put hc.OpenInputStream() after hc.getResponseCode() but it still doesn't work. Can you help me again please?